# postgres round works in some situations but not others

Tags: postgresql

I am using the round function to round numbers. Here is a working example:

```
select round(3.0/5,1);
```

I have a table called "ratings", which contains among other things a column called "rank".

Here is an example command and its output:

```
=> select rank from ratings limit 5;
rank
------
8.6
8.3
7.7
  7
7.9
(5 rows)
```

I would like the average rank, so I have done the following:

```
=> select avg(rank) from ratings;
avg
------------------
6.93997624861447
(1 row)
```

I would like to round this result so I have done the following:

```
=> select round(avg(rank)) from ratings;
round
-------
7
(1 row)
```

I would like to keep the first decimal place however so I tried this:

```
=> select round(avg(rank),1) from ratings;
ERROR:  function round(double precision, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: select round(avg(rank),1) from ratings;
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I find it extremely strange that this does work because I have tested round(float,int) already and it works (see the first example). Also round appears to work when passed no second argument.

Please explain what I am doing wrong so that I can fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ROUND` appears to work with exact numeric types, so you may try casting the average to numeric:

```
select round(cast(avg(rank) as numeric), 1) from ratings
```

The version of `ROUND` you are using requires a numeric type input, check the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-math.html).

Comment: Thanks! that works! Can you explain why mine doesn't work?

Comment: It doesn't work because you are passing float/double as the first argument.  ROUND needs an exact numeric input.